# Get values from a comma separated string containing less than a value

Tags: c#, regex

I am attempting to compare a comma separated string against a decimal variable and find only the amounts less than my variable.

The problem I'm having is my string looks like so:

> 1usd,5usd,10usd,20usd

I was able to separate the string into a collection by using the comma separator and regex split, but I don't think this is the best approach since I need to check just the value and reconstruct with the us and comma seperation.

A real world example my program will be handling is

```
decimal changeAvil = 10
notesSet = 1usd,5usd,10usd,20usd
```

Result should be notesSet = 1usd,5usd

Comment: If want to find only the amounts greater than your variable, then shouldn't your example result be `20usd`? That is the only value greater than 10.

Comment: You are correct. I edited my original post since I am looking for less than.

Comment: Please write a real title in English, don't just dump keywords into the title field.

Comment: So what is your question/problem?

Comment: Fix your input, so that you're not combining numbers and currency types, since they're not relevant to each other. Then you have no problems with numeric comparisons. If you decide to use improper input for your app, expect to have difficulties doing simple operations with that improper input. Think how much easier the task would be with two separate inputs,  *currency type* and *currency values*, then find the *currency values* less than a number.

Comment: Ken, the issue is I'm receiving this information from a middleware and it's already constructed this way. I need to take the values since it will pass other currency types if differnet and change within my application accordingly.

Comment: Then you need to strip off the parts that aren't numbers, convert the digits to actual numbers, and compare the values. Then do whatever you have to do to convert the results back to the originals. There's a penalty for having to suffer through bad design. I'd complain to whoever provides the middleware.

Comment: Are you sure you need to strip off parts that aren't numbers? If your “variable” is 10USD then 8GBP is greater than, not less.

Answer (score 0):

Its not the prettiest code that has ever been written, but is does the job. 
I use `Linq` to select the prefixes of the strings that are numbers, and then compare these to the value of `changeAvil`.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace stack
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            decimal changeAvil = 10;
            var noteSet = "1usd,5usd,10usd,20usd";
            var notes = noteSet.Split(',');
            var dict = 
                notes.ToDictionary(
                    x => int.Parse(new string(x.TakeWhile(c => char.IsNumber(c))
                                               .ToArray())), // key
                    x => x); // value

            var selection = dict.Where(kvp => kvp.Key <= changeAvil)
                                .Select(kvp => kvp.Value)
                                .ToList();
            foreach (var s in selection) {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The solution returns `1usd`, `5usd`, and `10usd`. If your do not want `10usd` to be part of the result change `kvp.Key <= changeAvil` to `kvp.Key < changeAvil` in the `Where` clause of the Linq expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can use split command and remove the letters 'usd' and then iterate through the array and compare

```
decimal changeAvil = 10
notesSet = 1usd,5usd,10usd,20usd
string noteset_new = noteset.Replace('usd',''); //remove usd
string[] noteset_array = noteset_new.split[',']; //split in to array
```

now you can iterate the above noteset_array and do what every you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Using replace and split on the string is using two iterations through the strings characters.
A better way to get the array will be to first add a comma to the end of the string and then use split:

```
notesSet = 1usd,5usd,10usd,20usd
string[] noteset_array = (notesSet + ',').split['usd,']; //split in to array
```